Как в JS сделать так чтобы события не исчезали при изменении html?
У меня есть код:


document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  console.log(e)
});
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="btn" id="btn1">Click</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>



При клике на кнопку в консоль выводится:

PointerEvent

Но если после события изменить html код то оно не выполниться.


document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  console.log(e)
});

document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML += `
  <h1>Hello</h1>
`;
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="btn" id="btn1">Click</button>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>



После данного изменения в JS коде при клике на кнопку событие не выполняется и в консоль ничего не выводится:

...

Подскажите как сделать так чтобы события не терялись при изменении HTML кода на JS? Заранее спасибо.

Используйте делегирование.

Спасибо большое! Делегирование событий очень помогло.

можно навешивать обработчики каждый раз после изменения

либо добавлять разметку не через innerHTML
